# How to check the compilation of cython’s pyxinport on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, compilation, cython, cythonize

I am working on a Cython project on Windows. I have created 2 files in my package directory:

- `module1.py`
- `module1.pyx`

After running the following code, invoking `pyximport`:

```
import pyximport; 
pyximport.install(build_dir='D:/Python01/cython/')

import module1 as cy
cy.fun_cython(5)
```

I could not find the .pyd or the .c file after compilation.

On Windows, where are these files located? How can I check if the compilation generated any errors?

Comment: The key phrase in your question here is “on Windows” – on anything besides Windows, these files show up in the same directory as the source from which they are derived.